# Is there a way to detect which turn of the event loop code is running in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

For the sake of understanding async and Fibers better, I'm wondering if there's a global variable that is incremented for each turn of the event loop.

I'd like to be able to see different values printed out in each of these console.log statements, and obviously we can't rely on system time to do so.

```
function getEventLoopCounter () { /* magic occurs */ }

// Turn 1 
console.log("I'm on loop number: ", getEventLoopCounter());

// Turn > 1 
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("I'm on different loop: ", getEventLoopCounter());
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) from the [Node timers module](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) will work. A quote from the documentation for [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg):

> To schedule the "immediate" execution of callback after I/O events
>   callbacks and before setTimeout and setInterval . Returns an
>   immediateObject for possible use with clearImmediate(). Optionally you
>   can also pass arguments to the callback.
>
> Callbacks for immediates are queued in the order in which they were
>   created. The entire callback queue is processed every event loop
>   iteration. If you queue an immediate from inside an executing
>   callback, that immediate won't fire until the next event loop
>   iteration.

Using function closures and recursion, you can then do:

```
var eventLoopCounter = 0;
setImmediate(function incrementEventLoopCounter() {
  eventLoopCounter++;
  setImmediate(incrementEventLoopCounter);
});
// Logging the total number of iterations every second.
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('The event loop has finished '
               + eventLoopCounter
               + ' iterations.');
}, 1000);
```

By the way, in the beginning of the `timers` module documentation, it states:

> All of the timer functions are globals. You do not need to require()
>   this module in order to use them.

And that is why `setImmediate` works without requiring the `timers` module.

I think I should note that I tried to do something similar using [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback), but I got an error preceded by a series of helpful warning messages that pointed me to the function above:

```
...
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Doesn't this run into an infinite "loop" that only increments the `eventLoopCounter`? The `incrementEventLoopCounter` function is always scheduled before the `setInterval` callback, which will never take place.

Comment: @Bergi Mmm...I don't think so. I tested it on node and it worked okay. Plus "the entire callback queue is processed every event loop iteration" and I believe the way `setInterval` works is that it checks to see if the main thread is busy, and if it is, it adds the function to the callback queue. So the next tick will not happen until the `setInterval` function completes.

Comment: "*If you queue an immediate from inside an executing callback, that immediate won't fire until the next event loop iteration.*" - ah, I should learn to read. Or get some sleep.